# Why is Ubercart sending order notification emails in plain text?

Tags: 7, ubercart, emails

I am using Ubercart 7.x3.1 and I am working with the Checkout rules (E-mail customer checkout notification and E-mail admin checkout notification).

I am using the default templates although these emails are sent in a very hard to read plain text. Am I missing a setting to allow these in HTML? How do I change this?

Comment: Drupal 7's default mail handler sends emails as plain text by default. Did you mean the email is a mess with unprocessed HTML in it or without line breaks ? 
I retagged your question with 7 and email tags.

Comment: I'm guessing the latter... email with no line breaks. So either way, I'm not seeing a solution. This should not be tagged at Drupal 7... per se. In our configuration, D7 is producing properly formatted HTML emails- but Ubercart receipts, for example are a mess, (e.g., no line breaks, etc)